# Creating a weak BLS

Tags: elliptic-curve-generation, bls-signature

I am exploring the implementation of a cryptographic signature that users can manually input, and I am willing to compromise security to a level where a hacker investing several thousand dollars in hardware can potentially crack it!

From my research, BLS seems suitable, but the standard signature size is too large for my application. Can I achieve a smaller signature by adjusting just the `P` value in the curve, or do I need to create a new curve with the desired `P` size? Also, is it straightforward to make a new pairing-friendly curve?

Comment: Yes, for EC you need a new **set** of Domain Parameters. Is BN256 already to large for you? It provides about ~100 bits of security rather than the expected ~128 bits. Obviously we're talking about an exponential scale for the security in bits to the amount of operations, and the field size will probably be linear with the strength even now it is diminished.  So to go to 80 of security bit you'll probably need ~201 bits fields size. For 64 bits we're talking about 173 field size and 50 bits about 128 bit key size. It would however be interesting to know if previous results could be re-used...

Comment: Thanks for your response. For my project, 64 bits of security should be enough, posing a challenge for attackers (I estimated it would take them years on a regular computer). Additionally, a 173-bit signature is practical for users to input manually. How can I obtain a curve for BLS that meets these requirements? Are there standard, simpler curves available, or an easy way to create them?

Comment: I'm leaving that to somebody more into this subject as I'm far less than sure that such a thing would even be 64 bit secure. I'm too afraid that breaking one of these keys would allow for a more speedy break of another. Precomputation attacks are definitely a thing for ECDH, so...