# Changing ECDSA for Shorter Signatures: deterministic k

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

I am exploring a modification to ECDSA to produce shorter signatures, even though it compromises security (in a controllable way). My rationale behind this change is in [this discussion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/110942/creating-a-weak-bls). In my application, the main focus is on keeping the signature short, while storage isn't as crucial.

Here is my new ECDSA method: (the notation I'm using aligns with [Wikipedia's ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm))

**During setup**, I generate a set of random values $( p_1, p_2, ..., p_{10} )$ which remain private to the signer. These values are then multiplied by the generator point $( G )$ to obtain corresponding points on the elliptic curve, denoted as $( Q_1 = p_1 \cdot G, Q_2 = p_2 \cdot G, ..., Q_{10} = p_{10} \cdot G )$, and shared with the verifier.

**In the signing phase**, instead of utilizing a random $ k $, I calculate it deterministically based on the input message, using $ k = \text{hash}(msg|1) \cdot p_1 + \text{hash}(msg|2) \cdot p_2 + ... $. The rest of the process follows the standard ECDSA, except the signer omits the $ r $ component, resulting in a signature half the size of normal ECDSA signatures.

**For verification**, the verifier can calculate $ r $ using the provided points $ (Q_1, Q_2,..,Q_{10}) $: $r=$ the $ x $ part of $ \text{hash}(msg|1) \cdot Q_1 + \text{hash}(msg|2) \cdot Q_2 + ... $.

I need to analyze the security of the proposed system. I think that an attacker with fewer than 10 signatures cannot compromise the system. However, once they exceed this threshold and has 10 equations in a finite field ($ s_i = {k_i}^{-1}(z_i + r_i d_{A}) $), does this imply the attacker can discover secrets?

Even if the system is breached after reaching 10 signatures, I can to adjust the number of points and a limit on the number of signatures. Is this scenario still secure?

Comment: I fear you want to optimize the signature size but discard what you pay in terms of storage of the various $Q$. Then, why don't you just precompute many $r$ instead of precomputing points ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In your suggestion, should I add a few more bits to the signature to show which precomputed $r$ is used? Also, I'm hopeful that my proposed method might offer better security than using a static $r$ but I'm still seeking analysis.

Comment: "However, once they exceed this threshold and has 10 equations in a finite field"; actually, I believe 11 signatures are needed; after all, there are 11 unknowns for the attacker to solve for ($p_1, ..., p_{10}, d_A)$.  However, once he has 11, recovering them is simple linear algebra (unless the 11 equations happen to not to be independent; quite a low probability of that happening)

Comment: Thanks. Does the fact that these equations are in a finite field provide any additional security? If the finite field doesn't have any effect, as you said, 11 signatures leaking all secrets.

Comment: No, it doesn't provide any additional security (given that we're in a nontiny finite field): linear algebra in a finite field is just like linear algebra anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to poncho and Ruggero, I've found my answer. With $n$ random points in the system, the maximum safe signing threshold is $n$. Beyond this, an attacker can compromise the system. Additionally, compared to precomputed $r$, the system offers slightly smaller signature sizes and a bit more flexibility.

Comment: Actually, the safe signing threshold is $n$ - with $n+1$ signatures, the attacker can easily compromise the system.